# ¿Como utilizar ajax para actualizar en tiempo real un crud en php?

Tags: php, ajax, crud

Hola a todos tengo esta duda, ya termine un crud que muestra pedidos pero en este momento no se como puedo hacer que conforme se agregue un nuevo pedido en la base de datos, mi archivo php se actualize para mostrar el ultimo pedido en la parte superior

Este es mi index:

```
<title><?php if(isset($page_title)) echo $page_title; ?></title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/personalizado.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class='table-responsive'> <table class='table-bordered table-striped'>
    <tr>
        <th>Cliente</th>


        <th>Orden de compra</th>


        <th>Productos</th>
        <th>Presentaciones</th>
                <th>Cantidades</th>
                <th>Fecha de embarque</th>
        <th>Notas</th>
        <th>Etiquetado</th>

        <?    if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){?>

        <th>Factura</th>

            <? } ?>


        <th>Salida de materiales</th>


        <th>Coa</th>


                <?    if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){?>


        <th colspan='2'>opciones de pedidos</th>
    <? } ?>




</tr>



        <?php 
  if ($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 1){
   $id =  $_SESSION['id'];

       $sql = "SELECT cliente FROM users WHERE id=:id";
            $q = $db->prepare($sql);
            $q->bindparam(':id', $id);
            $q->execute();
            $cliente = $q->fetchColumn();


            $query = "SELECT * FROM pedidos where cliente = '$cliente' order by id_pedido desc"; 

              $records_per_page=20;
        $newquery = $paginate->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $paginate->dataview($newquery);
        $paginate->paginglink($query,$records_per_page);

  }
    else{


        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                          include_once 'partials/busqueda.php';

            $busqueda = new busqueda($db);

                    $valor = $_POST['valor'];
                    $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
switch ($opcion) {
    case "orden_de_compra":
        $where = 'orden_de_compra';
        break;

    case "cliente":
                $where = 'cliente';
        break;
    case "productos":
                $where = 'producto';

        break;

         case "presentaciones":
                $where = 'presentacion';

        break;


         case "cantidades":
                $where = 'cantidad';

        break;


        case "fechas":
                $where = 'fecha_de_embarque';
       $valor = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($valor));

        break;
}

                          $query = "SELECT orden_de_compra, cliente, producto, presentacion, cantidad, fecha_de_embarque, notas, etiquetado,salida_materiales_terminada, coa_terminado, factura, file FROM detalle where $where = :valor order by id_detalle desc";  

                  $records_per_page=20;
        $newquery = $busqueda->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $busqueda->dataview($newquery,$valor);
        $busqueda->paginglink($query,$valor,$records_per_page);  






        }


else{
               $query = "SELECT orden_de_compra, cliente, productos, presentaciones, cantidades, fechas, notas, etiquetados, salida_materiales_terminada, coa_terminado, factura, file FROM pedidos order by id_pedido desc";  

                  $records_per_page=20;
        $newquery = $paginate->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $paginate->dataview($newquery);
        $paginate->paginglink($query,$records_per_page);  

        }



    }
    //registros mostrador por pagina

        ?>


</table>


        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
```

Y esta la clase de mi crud:

```
<?php

class paginate
{
     private $db;

     function __construct($db)
     {
         $this->db = $db;
     }

     public function dataview($query)
     {
         $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->execute();

         if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
         {
                while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                   ?>


                   <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $row['cliente']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row['orden_de_compra']; ?></td>

                       <?php

                $productos = str_replace("[x]","<br>----<br>",$row['productos']);

    echo "<td>". $productos."</td>";
            echo "<td>".str_replace("[x]","<br>----<br>",$row['presentaciones'])."</td>";   

        echo "<td>".str_replace("[x]","<br>----<br>",$row['cantidades'])."</td>";   

    $myString =  $row['fechas'];
    $myArray = explode('[x]', $myString);

    //codigo mostrar fecha
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($myArray as $fecha)
    {
                echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fecha)). "<br>----<br>";


    }

  echo  "</td>";
//


        echo "<td>".str_replace("[x]","<br>----<br>",$row['notas'])."</td>";    

            echo "<td>".str_replace("[x]","<br>----<br>",$row['etiquetados'])."</td>";  

                    $checkbox_checked = "<input type='checkbox'  checked onclick='return false;'";

             if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){
                                   if($row['factura'] == 0){



                                          echo "<td><a href=\"verdetalle.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Factura</a>
                                          <br><font color='red'>pend</font></td>";   
                                                      }
                                     else{

                                         echo "
                                         <td><a href=\"verdetalle.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Factura</a>
                                         <br>
                                         $row[file]
                                         <br>
                                         ";

                                         $limite = $row['factura'];
                                       for ($i = 0; $i < $limite; $i++) {

                                                echo "
                                       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                       "; 

                                             }
                                         echo "</td>";

                                     }

             }


                 if($row['salida_materiales_terminada'] == 1){

                                    echo "<td>";

                                                 if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){

                echo "<a href=\"formulariosalidademateriales.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Editar salida</a>
                <br>";
                                                 }


              echo  "<a href=\"pdfsalidademateriales.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></span></a>
                $checkbox_checked"; 

                     echo "</td>";
                 }

                 else{
                                                 if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){



                        echo "<td><a href=\"formulariosalidademateriales.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Completar salida</a><br><font color='red'>pendiente</font></td>";  

                                                 }

                 }




                                                      if($row['coa_terminado'] == 0){

                                                 if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){


                                          echo "<td><a href=\"formulariocoatorustrading.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Completar Coa</a>
                                          <br><font color='red'>pend</font></td>";  
                                                 }
                                                      }

                                     else{
                                         echo "<td>";

                                          if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){
                                                  echo "
                                         <a href=\"formulariocoatorustrading.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Coa</a>";


                                            }



                                       echo"<br>
                                         <a href=\"pdfcoa.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></span></a>
                                         <br>
                                         ";


                                         $limite = $row['coa_terminado'];
                                       for ($i = 0; $i < $limite; $i++) {

                                                echo "
                                       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                       "; 

                                             }
                                         echo "</td>";

                                     }








                                     if($_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] == 0){

        echo "<td><a href=\"verdetalle.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\" class='btn btn-primary'>Ver detalle</a></td> <td><a href=\"delete.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Esta seguro de que quiere eliminar su pedido?')\" class='btn btn-block btn-danger'>Eliminar</a></td>";
                                     }
?>

                   </tr>


                   <?php
                }
         }
         else
         {
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td>Nothing here...</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
         }

 }

 public function paging($query,$records_per_page)
 {
        $starting_position=0;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
             $starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
        }
        $query2=$query." limit $starting_position,$records_per_page";
        return $query2;
 }

 public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
 {

        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($total_no_of_records > 0)
        {
            ?><tr><td colspan="14"><?php
            $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
            $current_page=1;
            if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
            {
               $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
            }
              if(!isset($_GET["page_no"]))
            {
               $current_page=1;
            }

            if($current_page!=1)
            {
               $previous =$current_page-1;
               echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=1'>Ultimo</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
               echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Anterior</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            //cantidad de links de paginacion mostrados $i<=
            for($i=$current_page;$i<=$current_page+10;$i++)

            {
            if($i==$current_page)
            {
                echo "<strong><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;text-decoration:none'>".$i."</a></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            elseif($i!=$current_page and $i <= $total_no_of_pages)
            {
                echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }

                else {

                    break;
                }
   }
   if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
   {
        $next=$current_page+1;
        echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Siguiente</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Primero</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   }
   ?></td></tr><?php
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: crea funciones en el index para el código php, por ejemplo una función para la consulta de los pedidos, con eso cuando la necesites la vuelves a llamar, te recomendaria usar JQuery  para AJAX.

Comment: Ya utilizo algnas funciones, le paso en el index dependiendo del tipo de sesion un query  a una funcion de una clase en otro archivo php que incluyo al inicio, encontre esto pero estoy perdido porque en el archivo donde tengo mi tabla no imprimira nada sin el query y no se puede mandar el query por javascript al intentar actualizar?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681380/refresh-a-table-with-jquery-ajax-every-5-seconds